# Setting up visual aids to contextually update "grand totals" with drill-downs?

Tags: powerbi

In short, I would like to be able to adjust visual aids from displaying drilled-down results from a % of total (as represented by the entire pie below) to just the drilled-down data, as would be represented by a new pie that would scale the width of each field accordingly.  This is in contrast to the result that I am seeing right now, which filters the pie for the select data while keeping the original dimensions in confines with the view prior to the drill-down  The same would apply for other visual aids such as treemaps, column charts, etc.

What is driving me somewhat crazy is that this seems to work when I use a slicer, but NOT when I try drilling down on another visual aid (in this case, selecting a specific time period from a matrix window). So I am guessing that this is some setting that I have not found or fully understood yet. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the feature: **Edit Interactions**.  It's described in detail here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions

By (unfortunate) default Power BI chooses the **Highlight** setting for each new visual that supports that feature (e.g. donut chart). For your scenario you will want to change that to **Filter**.

You'll have to laboriously go through selecting almost every visual and checking/changing their interactions settings vs every other visual.

I would also turn on the option **Drilling filters other visuals**.  It's described at the bottom of that page.

FWIW I would not use a donut chart for that visualisation - there are too many categoies.  A Tree Map will make it much easier to compare categories as they are dynamically sorted by significance, and improve the visual data/space ratio.

Comment: You're welcome. Give me that little dopamine hit by marking as Answered.